# proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2}$ converges

Tags: calculus, limits

Give :  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2}$  need to prove that it converges.

So i know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2}=0$ but i can't find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }S_n$.

thanks.

Comment: Hint: You weren't asked to find the limit, only to show that it converges. $\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2} \le \frac{n}{3n^3} = \frac{1}{3n^2}$.

Comment: You wont be able to find the actual sum. Or at least its highly unlikely. Use the limit comparison theorem and compare it to the convergent series $\sum 1/n^2$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test

Comment: @Martingalo, the ratio test is always inconclusive in the case of a  series of rational terms.

Comment: aha, I just realized for this case, long time since my last series :) thanks

Comment: No worries. I only mention it, since it might help the OP in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2} \mathop{\sim} \limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{3n^{2}} $$

(which is to say that $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} 3n^{2}\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2} = 1$)

And the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{3n^2}$ converges. By comparison, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2}$ converges also !

Comment: why i need to say that $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} 3n^{2}\frac{n-2}{3n^3+2n^2} = 1$? isn't enough just to say that $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{3n^2}$ converges?

Comment: You don't have to say it, he is explaining the meaning of the expression with $\sim$.

Comment: The limit is the hypothesis you have to satisfy in order to use the limit comparison test. Your instructor would be looking for this on any exam.